# Javascript Searching for Index number of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would be very grateful if you could help me. I've been sitting here for 5 hours and can't find a solution. I want to get the number in the array based on the name of the array (ex. "Apfelkuchen"). In this case, "Apfelkuchen" would be number 0.

I know that the indexOF method is used for this, but unfortunately I don't know. How to use it, because my array is not the usual case.

```
let Essen = [

    { name: "Apfelkuchen", ingredients: ["Apfel", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },
    { name: "Bananenkuchen", ingredients: ["Banane", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },
    { name: "Käsekuchen", ingredients: ["Köse", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },
    { name: "Steuselkuchen", ingredients: ["Steuselkuchen", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },
    { name: "Schokokuchen", ingredients: ["Schoko", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },
    { name: "Kürbiskuchen", ingredients: ["Kürbis", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },
    { name: "Zitronenkuchen", ingredients: ["Zitronen", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },
    { name: "Erdbeerkuchen", ingredients: ["Erdbeere", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },
    { name: "Nusskuchen", ingredients: ["Nuss", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },
    { name: "Butterkuchen", ingredients: ["Butter", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },

];

function createEssen(_name, _ingredients) {
    Essen.push({name: _name, ingredients: _ingredients})
}

function addIngredients(_name) {
    Essen[10].ingredients.push(_name)
}

function searchArrayNumber(_name) {
    
How????

}
```

Comment: `indexOf()` would not help in your case because it only does a shallow comparison which means you would need to provide the same pointer to the object you want to search for. You will need to use `findIndex()` and compare the elements using the `name` property instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.findIndex()`:

```js
let Essen = [

    { name: "Apfelkuchen", ingredients: ["Apfel", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },
    { name: "Bananenkuchen", ingredients: ["Banane", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },
    { name: "Käsekuchen", ingredients: ["Köse", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },
    { name: "Steuselkuchen", ingredients: ["Steuselkuchen", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },
    { name: "Schokokuchen", ingredients: ["Schoko", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },
    { name: "Kürbiskuchen", ingredients: ["Kürbis", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },
    { name: "Zitronenkuchen", ingredients: ["Zitronen", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },
    { name: "Erdbeerkuchen", ingredients: ["Erdbeere", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },
    { name: "Nusskuchen", ingredients: ["Nuss", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },
    { name: "Butterkuchen", ingredients: ["Butter", "Mehl", "Zucker"] },

];


console.log(Essen.findIndex(x => x.name == "Apfelkuchen"));
```

Comment: Thanks works well, have a nice day :)